# Is there a way to see which pixels are what coordinates with crosshairs on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

Is there a tool that will do this?  I want to be running the simulator and then be able to put the mouse over some point and have it tell me what the (x,y) coordinates are.  Surely there's a simple tool that does this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Developer Tools -> Applications -> Graphics Tools there is a program called Pixie. It will do what you want. In Preferences you can set it up so that an option-drag will count pixels. You can also set it to just show the pixel coordinates and do the math yourself.

[image: Pixie is under Additional Tools for XCode]

Comment: Not soo good, because you can't set the (0,0) point, so you will need to calculate by manually.

Comment: In version 3, you have to lock the screen first (with ctrol+option+command+L), and then you can use option+drag to measure pixels.

Comment: For others: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=pixie Now pixie is to be downloaded separately. earlier it was included in XCode bundle.

Answer (score 25):

I just use the built-in screenshot snapper from OS X. Just Command+Shift+4 and when you drag it shows the dimensions of the snap you'd take. Press escape to drop it. Works great.

Comment: HAHA! Saved my ass! I use that tool all the time but totally overlooked the x,y being displayed, which is exactly what I needed! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've used the Iconfactory's [xScope](http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope) for this before.  If you create rulers that are the size of the display in the Simulator, you can get a readout of the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer as you move across the Simulator screen.  Getting the rulers precisely aligned with the edge of the Simulator screen can be a little tricky for applications with dark backgrounds, though.

Answer (score 1):

While troubleshooting UI design issues in my `.NET MAUI` app for `iOS`, I adopt the following approach:

1. In the `iOS Simulator` click on `Window -> Point Accurate`.
   More info about iOS Simulator resize options can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-simulator-for-your-environment#Resize-a-simulator-window).
2. Launch the [Digital Colour Meter](https://support.apple.com/en-za/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac) app, which comes preinstalled with macOS, and configure the zoom level for optimal accuracy:

   - Adjust the size of the aperture to the lowest value.
   - Set magnification level to maximum: `View -> Magnification -> 8x`.
   - Enable mouse coordinates: `View -> Show Mouse Location`.
3. Utilize the point preview in the `Digital Colour Meter` app to identify areas on the screen, you are interested in, and use built-in `screenshot app from macOS` to commence measuring:

   - Use `Command+Shift+4` to view the width and height of selection, pressing escape to discard it. For example:

     [image]
   - Use `Command+Shift+5` to keep selection on screen if you need to reuse it for comparison with some other UI elements. Escape works here as well.

Notes:

- `Digital Colour Meter` offers additional features. Some of them are:

  - Options to lock point on screen by X coordinate or Y coordinate which is useful for checking alignment of UI elements.
  - Option to copy color(as text) of point under mouse pointer.
  - Options to display color codes as decimal or hexadecimal.
- If you would like a larger appearance for everything on the screen, consider utilizing the `zoom options in macOS`. Further details can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40579/mac).
- If you frequently perform actions in mentioned apps and you don't like combinations of keyboard shortcuts used there or those are not even set for example for some options in `Digital Colour Meter`, you can create/modify those keyboard shortcuts via `macOS keyboard shortcut settings`. More info about those can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh26782/mac) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/mac).